# Froala - How to add more tabs in color popup or add custom color buttons?

Tags: jquery, froala

As stated in the question I am trying to find out if there was a way to add more tabs to the color popup or a way to add more custom color buttons. I have added an input inside an empty froala element and whenever you change color of element from editor then I have hacked it to change the text color of the input and same for background but now I want a third color picker to change the border color. Any way to do so?

If anyone wants to know how I hacked it then here is the code. Maybe I can do some changes there?

```
$('.froala-editor-input')
    .keydown(false) // Don't let user type anything
    .froalaEditor({
        key: froalaKey,
        toolbarInline: true,
        charCounterCount: false,
        toolbarVisibleWithoutSelection: true,
        toolbarButtons: [
            'showMoreBtn', 'bold', 'align', 'horGridAlign', 'boxShadow', 'color', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', '-', 
            'radiusBtn', 'rightToLeft', 'leftToRight', 'undo', 'redo'
        ]
    })
    .on('froalaEditor.commands.after', function (e, editor, cmd, param1, param2) {
        // console.log(e);
        // console.log(editor, cmd, param1, param2);
        if(cmd == 'textColor'){
            $('.ui-selected input').css('color',param1+' !important');

            // remove previous styles
            $('#fr-styles').remove();
            // create a new <style> element, set its ID
            var $style = $('<style>').attr('id', 'fr-styles');
            // create the style string: it's the text node of our <style> element
            $style.text(
                '::placeholder { ' +
                    'color: '+param1+' !important'+
                '}');
            // append it to the <head> of our document
            $style.appendTo('head');
        }
        if(cmd == 'backgroundColor'){
            $('.ui-selected input').css('background',param1);
        }
    });
```

HTML is as follows :

```
<div class="froala-editor-input">
    <input/>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe if you could link to a working demo ...

Comment: Do you want a demo of how froala color button works? Here is the demo for custom color button.

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/colors